# Caching LinqToSql Entity

Tags: linq-to-sql, caching

I have an entity which has numerous linked entityset objects on it, what I'm not sure about is if I cache this object do the entityset links get resolved and their results cached along with the top level object. In otherwords does the whole object graph get cached?

Answer (score 0):

As long as the `DataContext` is active, it should cache retrieved data.